# webview transparent background

Tags: cocoa, macos, webview

In a WebView i am loading html file.The html page is displayed with black background.
I want it to be semitransparent. If I set setAlphaValue: then webview content transparency changes. Is there a way to set (or control) transparency of html background.

Editing html file would be last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Edit the HTML or CSS:

```
<body style="background-color: transparent">
body{background-color:transparent;}
```

**Option 2:** Apply the transparency using JavaScript:

```
evaluateWebScript:
```

**EDIT**

Snippet related to second option:

```
NSString * source = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><div id=\"box\">Example Box</div></body></html>";
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:source baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] ];
[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:@"document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';"]; // Change box background
[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:@"document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';"]; // Change body background
```