# Change background, fontColor of page loaded into WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, background-color, google-translate

Is it possible to change the background of website loaded into WebView? I think it is not possible, but for example webView.getSettings() allows to set FontSize of WebView, so maybe there is any way to set also the backround of page that was loaded?

I have found some solutions, but they are not for android (I don't know how to use them)...

- [Change contents background color in UIWebView in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643918/change-contents-background-color-in-uiwebview-in-xcode)
- [webview transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044781/webview-transparent-background)
- [Android WebView style background-color:transparent ignored on android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2)

I am trying to load http://translate.google.com/m with black background and white font color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set webview background color then 
use : -

```
       webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Comment: Solution is not that simple. WebView loads data from HTML, so it set page background to color provided by HTML code...